# Salesforce Scheduler Service Appointment Time Screen throwing "There is no active Work Type Group" error when running on Community

Tags: lightning-scheduler

I am facing an issue related to the Salesforce Scheduler only in community when scheduling an appointment.

I have created a new flow for scheduling appointments by using the Inbound New Appointment flow template and I have done minor changes to the flow.

Additionally, I have created records for everything like territory, service resource, work types, workgroups, operating hours, time-slots but when I am scheduling an appointment in community, on the Service Appointment Time Screen its showing me an error "There is no active Work Type Group".

I have also tried to debug the custom Inbound New Appointment flow within the salesforce as a community user and everything is working fine but not in the community.

I am not able to understand the issue here as it is working fine within Salesforce.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you are not logged in as any user while using the community, the root cause of the error might be because the `Guest User Profile` does not have the right permission to the records. to double check you can go to the Site Builder, then select Settings (on the left hand side menu) and under General option, you should see a link to go to the Guest User Profile. make sure it has read or/and edit access to all objects

Comment: Have you assigned the 'Lightning Scheduler' permission set license to the community user?

Comment: @Swetha Yes, I have assigned the permission set to the community user.

Comment: @McCubo I am scheduling an appointment as a community user which is working fine within salesforce when debugging the flow as a Community User.

Comment: Have you found a resolution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @CoryO.Bennett I have not found any resolution yet.

Comment: Have you set the sharing rules for the Guest user as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_guest_sharing_criteria.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and I have updated the OWD as Public Read Only for all scheduler objects like "Work Type, Work Type Group, Service Resource, etc". This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. It turns out the sharing rules were missing, cf: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_guest_sharing_criteria.htm&type=5

Comment: Salesforce does not have a good reputation when it comes to link longevity. Please [edit] your answer to reproduce the important parts of that link here so that this answer can still be useful when (not if, when) Salesforce decides to change their link format again.